# Elegant Way To Store Dotfiles on GitHub

Tags: symlink, git, home, dot-files, github

I need an elegant solution to store my dotfiles on GitHub for easy access. I tried to create a `dotfiles` directory and symlink all the dotfiles into there. Then I tried adding the symlinks to git and committing in that directory, but `git` saves the links not the contents of the files it points to. Is there a way to do this or something similar?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I have no idea what the *best* approach is and elegance is certainly in the eye of the beholder, but I use the following for my dotfiles:

- A `~/.dotfiles` directory that contains all of the dotfiles themselves. These are all managed in a git repo.
- A script, also in `~/.dotfiles` that creates the required links into my home directory. I don't have any dotfiles in my home directory, only links into `~/.dotfiles`. For example:

  ```
  $ ls -l ~/.muttrc
  lrwxr-xr-x  1 mj  mj  25 May  4  2014 /home/mj/.muttrc -> /home/mj/.dotfiles/muttrc
  ```

After I've cloned the repo onto a new machine (into `~/.dotfiles`), I just run the script to update the symlinks.

I've found the above approach works very well for me.

Comment: This works for me for more basic files but when I try to symlink something like my `.oh-my-zsh/custom` directory, `zsh` does not follow the symlink and says my theme cannot be found

Comment: I don't use oh-my-zsh but I'm guessing that you *may* need to symlink the files below `~/.oh-my-zsh` and not the directory itself. My dotfiles setup is fairly complex (with subrepos below it for various vim addons, etc) and I've not run into any issues with it.

Comment: Yeah just a pain to have to create and symlink every file I create rather than have all files in directory automatically symlinked but I can deal with it

Comment: @cabellicar123, see also: https://dotfiles.github.io/